# Console.log sentencia sql en c#

Tags: c#, mysql

La siguiente linea no me funciona por lo que queria a ver si puedo saber que insert hace cuando hago click, ya que no me inserta nada en la base de datos y no me da ningun error.

```
alta = new AltaComunicados(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["gestionTienda"].ConnectionString);
```

Como podria saber el insert que hace en `C#` y `ASP.Net`?

La clase es la siguiente:

```
    public class AltaComunicados : Productos, IComparable<AltaComunicados>
    {
        protected new string m_strCodigo;
        protected string m_strTitulo;
        protected string m_strURL;
        protected string m_strFecha;
        protected int m_nOrden;

        public new string Codigo { get { return m_strCodigo; } set { m_strCodigo = value; m_bModificado = false; } }
        public string Titulo { get { return m_strTitulo; } set { m_strTitulo = value; m_bModificado = true; } }
        public string URL { get { return m_strURL; } set { m_strURL = value; m_bModificado = true; } }
        public string Fecha { get { return m_strFecha; } set { m_strFecha = value; m_bModificado = true; } }
       // public string Claves { get { return m_strClaves; } set { m_strClaves = value; m_bModificado = true; } }
        public int Orden { get { return m_nOrden; } set { m_nOrden = value; m_bModificado = true; } }

        public AltaComunicados(string cadCon)
            : base(cadCon, null)
        {
            //
            // TODO: Add constructor logic here
            //
            m_strTablaDatos = "comunicados";
        }

        protected override object ValorColumna(string nombreColumna)
        {
            object resultado = null;

            switch (nombreColumna)
            {
                case "Codigo":
                    resultado = m_strCodigo;
                    break;
                case "Titulo":
                    resultado = m_strTitulo;
                    break;
                case "URL":
                    resultado = m_strURL;
                    break;
                case "Fecha":
                    resultado = m_strFecha;
                    break;
               // case "claves":
                 //   resultado = m_strClaves;
                   // break;
                case "Orden":
                    resultado = m_nOrden;
                    break;
            }
            return resultado;
        }

        protected override void ValorColumna(string nombreColumna, object valor)
        {
            switch (nombreColumna)
            {
                case "Codigo":
                    m_strCodigo = Convert.ToString(valor);
                    break;
                case "Titulo":
                    m_strTitulo = Convert.ToString(valor);
                    break;
                case "URL":
                    m_strURL = Convert.ToString(valor);
                    break;
                case "Fecha":
                    m_strFecha = Convert.ToString(valor);
                    break;
              //  case "claves":
                //    m_strClaves = Convert.ToString(valor);
                  //  break;
                case "Orden":
                    m_nOrden = Convert.ToInt32(valor);
                    break;
            }
        }

        protected override void LimpiaCampos()
        {
            m_strCodigo = "";
            m_strTitulo = "";
            m_strURL = "";
            m_strFecha = "";
         //   m_strClaves = "";
            m_nOrden = 0;
        }

        protected override void GeneraListaCampos()
        {
            m_lstrNombresCampos.Clear();

            m_lstrNombresCampos.Add("Codigo");
            m_lstrNombresCampos.Add("Titulo");
            m_lstrNombresCampos.Add("URL");
            m_lstrNombresCampos.Add("Fecha");
           // m_lstrNombresCampos.Add("claves");
            m_lstrNombresCampos.Add("Orden");
        }


        int IComparable<AltaComunicados>.CompareTo(AltaComunicados other)
        {
            return m_nOrden.CompareTo(other.m_nOrden);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Buenas, tendrías que añadir que hace la clase AltaComunicados, ya que con la información que das no podemos ver nada.

Comment: La clase AltaComunicados hace un insert de los datos que pongo en el formulario. La cuestión es que una vez hago el insert, si me sale listado ese insert, pero cuando cierro y abro de nuevo la página ya no sale listado porque no se ha llegado a insertar en la base de datos.

Comment: Como te comenta @lDanny7 sin ver el código de AltaComunicados es muy dificil ayudarte. Revisa si estas dentro de una transacción, ya que si es asi debes hacer un commit para que realmente se inserte en la base de datos.

Comment: Si tienes acceso a la clase `AltaComunicados`, podrías añadir ahí dentro el Log, simplemente imprime el string con la consulta.

Comment: en que parte del codigo ejecutas el INSERT ? porque en el codigo que publicas no se observa donde esta el ExecuteNonQuery() del MySqlCommand

Comment: Hola. Me he dado cuenta que el error lo tenia en el : m_lstrNombresCampos.Add("Codigo"); No insertaba correctamente ese campo, debido al tipo de dato que guardava en la base de datos. Muchas gracias.